# Adding Zero to a column in first x rows in R

Tags: r, zero, sapply, rep

I am creating a classification model for forecasting purposes. I have several ext files which I converted into one large list containing several lists (called comb). I then broke the large list into a separate dataframe with each list as its own column (called BI). Because each list may contain different number of elements, the simpler argument matrix(unlist(l), ncol=ncol) does not work. When reviewing alternatives, I made modification to compile the following:

```
max_length <- max(sapply(comb,length))

BI<-sapply(comb, function(x){
c(x, rep(0, max_length - length(x)))
})
```

This creates a dataframe assigning each list a column and assigning each missing element within that column a value of ZERO. Those zeros show at the end of that column but I would like them to be at the beginning of the column. Here is an example of current output:

```
cola colb colc
2    2    2   
1    1    0
4    0    0
```

I need your help in converting my original code to produce the following format:

```
acola colb colc
2    0    0   
1    2    0
4    1    2
```

Comment: Where is the original list `comb`?  That seems kinda important

Comment: what you want is to have all zeros, if any, "at the top" of every column? could you post with `dput` some of your list?

Comment: @VincentBonhomme & Hadd E. Nuff the dput is a large output but essentially comb is a list of 15 lists (all numeric, different number of elements, with numbers ranging from 0 to 18000).

Comment: @VincentBonhomme Yes to your question ('what you want is to have all zeros, if any, "at the top" of every column')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be sufficient to interchange the order in the concatenation `c`:

```
max_length <- max(sapply(comb, length))

BI <- sapply(comb, function(x){
    c(rep(0, max_length - length(x)), x)
})
```

---

EDIT: Based on additional information in the comments below, here's an approach that modifies the code in another way.  The idea is that as long as your first approach gives
you a proper data frame, we can circumvent the problem by using
the `order`-function.

```
max_length <- max(sapply(comb,length))

BI <- sapply(comb, function(x){
    .zeros <- rep(0, max_length - length(x))
    .rearange <- order(c(1:length(x), .zeros))
    c(x, .zeros)[.rearange]
})
```

I have tested that this code works upon a minor test example I
created, but I'm not certain that this example resembles your
`comb`...

If this revised approach doesn't work, then it's still possible
to first create the data frame with your original code, and
then reorder one column at the time.

Comment: But if we have a list, then I think we can use 'data.frame' upon it to create the desired result.

Comment: I had tried converting it into a dataframe but just did not mention it in my original response. I get this error `Error in data.frame(c(49.04, 48.7, 48.049997, 48.069997, 48.379999, 48.259999,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 4666, 2686, 4431, 4627`. This differing number of rows is the same issue my original code tried to resolve so we are back at square one.

Comment: your edited version worked well. I have a few questions on what you did and I will spend some time now to try and figure it out. Thank you for your help.